# How to create variables for use in Xcode build settings values?

Tags: xcode4, xcode5

XCode has a number of built-in variables that are used for convenience in Build Settings, for example `"$(PRODUCT_NAME)"` or `"$(CURRENT_ARCH)"`.

Can I define my own variables? How / where?

Answer (score 124, accepted):

In XCode 5 this has changed slightly.

1. Select the project or target in the left side of the editor
2. Go to the Editor menu in the top menu bar
3. Select "Add Build Setting" and then "Add User-Defined Build Setting"

[image]

Comment: is there any way to add a user defined build settings which can select a value from set of predefined values

Comment: When the selections are grayed out (like in the image above), you need to select the Project from the "Project and Target" list, then click the "Build Settings" tab, as specified in this SO question and answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19842746/adding-a-build-configuration-in-xcode

Comment: @Johnykutty this may be useful http://blog.xebia.com/2015/01/30/run-your-ios-app-without-overwriting-the-app-store-version/

Comment: Can this be considered a kind of Obfuscation?

Answer (score 17):

It's at the top of the build settings panel in Xcode 10.

[image]

Answer (score 13):

Create a user-defined build setting. To create one in Xcode 4 select your project from the project navigator to open the project editor. Select your project or target from the left side of the editor. Click the Build Settings button at the top of the editor. Click the Add Build Setting button at the bottom of the editor and choose Add User-Defined Setting.

Comment: The original accepted answer, back in Xcode 4 days.

Answer (score 7):

User-defined setting can be added in Xcode as specified below:

Xcode 4.x :

Select PROJECT /  TARGETS -> “Add Build Setting” (option present in bottom-right corner of Xcode)
-> “Add User-Defined Setting”

[image]

Xcode 5.x :

Select PROJECT /  TARGETS -> Editor menu -> “Add Build Setting“ -> “Add User-Defined Setting”

[image]

This will add User-defined setting. Enter key-value for setting.

Comment: is there any way to add a user defined build settings which can select a value from set of predefined values

Comment: yes, there is a way to define values to preprocessor variables in build settings, which can be accessed from code. Goto `"Apple LLVM - Preprocessing"` section in `Build Settings` of your project and you can add variables like `LOGGING=1` and which can be accessed from code as `#if LOGGING`.

Comment: It seems that on Xcode 12.5, the Editor menu doesn't work, but the top-right add button next to search bar does now.