# Declare a common Xcode variable for use in plist for all Xcode targets in a project/workspace

Tags: xcode, xcode7

I have an Xcode project, which has multiple targets. I want to define a variable somewhere (a variable for build number, to be precise) where I can reference as the `Bundle version` in the Info.plist of each project without updating them individually. e.g. I'll set bundle version to `$(BUILD_NUMBER)` once (I've made up the name) for each target then I'll increment that `BUILD_NUMBER` variable on each release. Is this possible? If yes, how? I've seen [Adding a build configuration in Xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19842746/adding-a-build-configuration-in-xcode) and [How to create variables for use in Xcode build settings values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10854156/how-to-create-variables-for-use-in-xcode-build-settings-values) but the settings are greyed out:

[image]

Comment: First, you need to go to "Build Settings" and select a configuration (possibly Debug or Release). Then "Add Conditional Setting" or "Add User-Defined Setting" will be enabled. This [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-project_editor/Articles/Adding%20a%20Conditional%20Build%20Setting.html) partially illustrates how it is done. Second, it might be pain in the ass to manually increment build number as other developers step in and start working at the same project. You might want to consider using some CI solutions like `fastlane` instead.

Comment: @ozgur it worked perfectly. could you please post it as an answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: Frankly, my answer doesn't cover your actual question about how to alter a user-defined variable programmatically thus, I'd rather leave my answer as is. But, glad to hear it worked for you.

Comment: @ozgur actually my question was mainly about being able to declare a common variable, auto incrementing would be nice but isn't mandatory.

Comment: @ozgur and using a CI solution solely for build number increment would be a bit overkill in my case :) but that's okay

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to go to `Build Settings` and select a configuration (possibly Debug or Release). Then **Add Conditional Setting** or **Add User-Defined Setting** options will be enabled. This [link](https://medium.com/@kavithakumarasamy89/xcode-build-settings-user-defined-settings-manage-multiple-environments-with-single-target-3e5c1a307999) illustrates how it is done.

Second, it might be error-prone to manually increment build number especially after some other developers step in and start working on the same project. You might want to consider using some CI solutions like [fastlane](https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane) instead. It makes use of [`agvtool`](https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/qa/qa1827/_index.html)  for app versioning so you might want to also look at that as well.

Comment: it works perfectly. just a quick addition: I didn't select a configuration such as debug or release, I've just went to the build settings of the projects and followed the steps. it applies to both debug and release (or any other configuration), which is what I need anyway.