# Maintain Two Projects differ only icons ,splashscreens and bundle identifier

Tags: xcode, version

I have two projects in which all the source code is same and only difference is i have to maintain different

`icons, splash screens, bundle identifier, Version Number and some constant file`

for each project.

How can i do this,Can any one suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Hey you can use different build targets. Every target will have a different info.plist file. In this file you can specify icon, splash screens, displayed name ...

The bundle identifier is described in:

[iPhone/Xcode: can different project targets have different bundle identifiers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/792170/iphone-xcode-can-different-project-targets-have-different-bundle-identifiers)

Cheers Stefan